# Phonegap and nexus s - input type=text not taking input

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, nexus-s

I am building an app using Phonegap and jQuery mobile...

On my `index.html` page, I have an `anchor` tag which opens another page as `dialog`

`<a href="passcode.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">`

and my `passcode.html` file is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body> 
        <div idata-role="dialog">

            <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
                <h1>Enter Passcode</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
                <input type="password"/>
                <br/>
                <input type="button" value ="Access Cards"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the first `anchor` this dialog pops up.
Now the problem is everything works fine on `iPhone` `iPad` `Android Simulator`
But When I tap on the text input on my `Nexus S` the key board pops up but when I try to type nothing is show in the inout field.

Cursor is shown, which means its focused. Keyboard is also show. But Input field doesn't get typed.

Here is the screen shot... Anyone had any similar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568239/cant-edit-input-type-text-or-textarea-with-cordova-1-9-0-and-android-jelly-be) indicates that if you're on android 4.1, you'll need to upgrade your phonegap project to 2.0.