# Can't Type In Textbox In IE AngularJS/Cordova/Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, textbox, focus

I'm developing an application with Cordova 3 tools for VS2013(Cordova Version 3.6.4). When I deploy to local machine in Windows I get the following behaviors for `<input type="text>`:

- I am unable to type in any `<input type="text>`.
- When i give focus to the `<input type="text>` the cursor randomly blinks in other places.

Even with the following markup, `<input type="text" name="name" value=" " />`, as the first node in the `<body>` I get this behavior.

Debugging I have done:

- Used ng-focus to see what element has the focus and it is the correct element.
- Used ng-keypress and it also references the correct element.
- Checked on Chrome and does not have this problem.

**My current solution**

I changed the `<input type="text>` to a `<textarea style="height:34px;">`. I would rather it worked as it should but this should suffice for now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't edit input type="text" or textarea with Cordova 1.9.0 and Android Jelly Bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568239/cant-edit-input-type-text-or-textarea-with-cordova-1-9-0-and-android-jelly-be)

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion that it might be a duplicate but its not. `*user-select: none;` does not exist in the solution and the cordova version number is 3.6.4. And again this is only happening on IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue would appear to be related to CSP (Content Security Policy) rules of Universal Windows Apps (IE) (and interestingly also Chrome Extensions.

The fix is simple and involves putting the ng-csp in the **html** element on your page. This will allow you to regain edit control of your input elements (text boxes). Your code should look like

```
<html ng-csp>
```

More reading here: [AngularJS Documentation ng-csp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)