# Unable to type in ionic text box

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have login screen with username and password text fields.
I have used ionic input type text.
I have applied following css to make parent div horizontally & vertically center.

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);         
}
```

When I remove this class I can type in textbox of android device.
But when I add this class I unable to type in textboxes of android device.
Keyboard opens properly but do not show text on typing.
Text shows properly on textbox focus out.
Whats an issue??

Comment: For what do you need the transform?

Comment: I use transform to make my div vertically and horizontally center

Comment: Have you thought about using the Ionic Grid instead? http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-vertically-align

Comment: @JeremyWilken thanks, I tried with ionic grid and its working fine now.Still wonder why input boxes was not working with my 'wrapper' class ?

Comment: I would need a more complete example to give it a try, but I suspect it has to do with how the positioning of elements works and how the keyboard changes the available space for positioning items.

Comment: This issue has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568239/cant-edit-input-type-text-or-textarea-with-cordova-1-9-0-and-android-jelly-be)